# How to populate a WebGrid cell with a collection of ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I have a Model like so:

```
class Model
{
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public AnotherType[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

And a View that takes an `IEnumerable<Model>` that I am displaying in a WebGrid using Razor and asp.net MVC 4.

So far I have:

```
@{ var grid = new WebGrid(Model); }
<div id="grid">
      @grid.GetHtml(
          columns: 
              grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("Text")))
</div>
```

What I would like is to create a list of comma separated list of links based on the value of `Values` in my model in the second column.

I have tried just creating a Linq query to project them into `ActionLink`s, (or even a String Array and use String.Join() to test it) but that doesn't compile at Runtime.

For example:

```
grid.Column("Values",
    format: (item) => String.Join(item.Select(v => v.Property).ToArray()))))
```

The error I get is (I think):

> error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a
>   dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a
>   delegate or expression tree type

I'd like my output to look like:

```
|--------------------------------|
|**Text**  | **Values**          |
|--------------------------------|
|Text A    | Val 1, Val 2, Val 3 |
|--------------------------------|
```

Where `Val n` is a link that can navigate you away to view more detail.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

As a workaround, I have combined the values in my Model and expose a `String` property with the result, but this doesn't allow me to create `ActionLink`s.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the item (dynamic) as AnotherType

```
(item).Cast<AnotherType>()
```